# Python interactive plotting with click events

Tags: python, plotly

I'm currently trying to bring in some data through np, do some processing on that initial data, plot it, but then be interactive with my plot. Plotly has a tutorial of how to take the plot and change the color of the data points (in jupyter using the click event https://plotly.com/python/click-events/). What I'm hoping to do is be able to take the click event click on 2 points and then create a line between the points selected and gather my positions of the line. The only thing I have found in plotly is just hovering over the data but not being able to do this processing. Is there a better way of doing this rather than using plotly? The documentation on plotly is suggesting to just use dash, but I haven't found a way of doing this with dash. The follow-up question would be how do I get this data if I export my plot (`fig.write_html`)?

Sample of what I have is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


x=np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=50)
y=np.sin(x)

fig=go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers')])

fig.update_layout(template='simple_white')

scatter=fig.data[0]
colors=['#a3a7e4']*100
scatter.marker.color=colors
scatter.marker.size=[10]*100
fig.layout.hovermode='closest'

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(line=dict(color='DarkSlateGrey')))

# create our callback function
def update_point(trace, points, selector):
    c = list(scatter.marker.color)
    s = list(scatter.marker.size)
    for i in points.point_inds:
        c[i]='#bae2be'
        s[i]=20
        with fig.batch_update():
            scatter.marker.color=c
            scatter.marker.size=s

scatter.on_click(update_point)

fig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- given you attempted example is **ipwidgets** I have extended this
- create an empty trace that will be target for lines
- for debugging create `widgets.Output()`
- now just a case of creating UI using `HBox()` and `VBox()`
- for now have demonstrated how you can export by printing to **stdout**.  This clearly could save the JSON to a file

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json
import ipywidgets as widgets

x=np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=50)
y=np.sin(x)

fig=go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers'), go.Scatter(x=[], y=[], mode="lines")])

fig.update_layout(template='simple_white')

scatter=fig.data[0]
line = fig.data[1]
colors=['#a3a7e4']*100
scatter.marker.color=colors
scatter.marker.size=[10]*100
fig.layout.hovermode='closest'

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(line=dict(color='DarkSlateGrey')))

out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
out.append_stdout('Output appended with append_stdout\n')

# create our callback function
@out.capture()
def update_point(trace, points, selector):
    x = list(line.x) + points.xs
    y = list(line.y) + points.ys
    line.update(x=x, y=y)
scatter.on_click(update_point)

reset = widgets.Button(description="Reset")
export = widgets.Button(description="Export")

@out.capture()
def on_reset_clicked(b):
    line.update(x=[], y=[])
    out.clear_output()
@out.capture()
def on_export_clicked(b):
    print(fig.to_dict()["data"][1])

reset.on_click(on_reset_clicked)
export.on_click(on_export_clicked)

widgets.VBox([widgets.HBox([reset, export]), widgets.VBox([fig, out])])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! Do you know if there's a way to have this functionality if I try to create my plot in a pop out window instead of inline from jupyter?

Comment: I've not used **ipwidgets** extensively, but would suspect not.  if you used **dash** and callbacks from it I would expect pop outs to work